# Android :: Custom Dialog with number scrollable picker?

Tags: android, dialog

**PROBLEM**

What we call this component in the red circle ??

and how can I make dialog that have it on like this.

actually I don't know what its called so I don't know keyword

to search about that. I'm sorry if it feel like weird question.

**NOTE**

I know how to create simple dialog in android anyway

[image]

Comment: That is a NumberPicker. See http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/NumberPicker.html

Comment: Is it possible to add degree symbol in each number??

Comment: Yes it is. Using setDisplayedValues() method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Imagine you want to have a `NumberPicker` that displays degree values from 0C to 20C.

You have to set a String array to populate your NumberPicker.

First, initialize your String [] with your values, like this:

```
    String [] degreesValues = new String [20];

    for(int i= 0;i<20;i++){
        degreesValues[i] = String.valueOf(i)+ (char) 0x00B0;
    }
```

Then, just apply that array on your `NumberPicker`, like this:

```
NumberPicker picker = (NumberPicker) findViewById(R.id.numberPicker);
    picker.setMinValue(0);
    picker.setMaxValue(19);
    picker.setDisplayedValues(degreesValues);
```